# Creating an incremental count variable in XSLT / XPath when using Xpath for..in..return?

Tags: variables, xslt, xpath, for-loop, count

I am using the XPath for loop equivalent -

```
<xsl:for-each select="for $i in 1 to $length return $i">...
```

And I really need a count variable, how would I achieve this?

Thanks,

Ash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following requires no additional namespaces. The solution contains a template called `iterate` that is called from within itself and which updates `$length` and `$i` accordingly:

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:call-template name="iterate"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="iterate">
        <xsl:param name="length" select="5"/>
        <xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
        <pos><xsl:value-of select="$i"/></pos>
        <xsl:if test="$length > 1">
            <xsl:call-template name="iterate">
                <xsl:with-param name="length" select="$length - 1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <pos>1</pos>
    <pos>2</pos>
    <pos>3</pos>
    <pos>4</pos>
    <pos>5</pos>
</root>
```

Comment: Not sure why this incredibly verbose solution has been accepted when other responses suggest a much more succinct solution.

Comment: I have to agree with @MichaelKay I originally misread the question and was under the impression `for $i in 1 to $length return $i` didn't work and was just a concept, the answer provided by Michael (and Martin) works as required.

Answer (score 10):

First note that

```
for $i in 1 to $length return $i
```

is just a long-winded way of writing

```
1 to $length
```

Within the for-each, you can access the current integer value as "." or as `position()`.

Answer (score 6):

Inside of the

```
<xsl:for-each select="for $i in 1 to $length return $i">...</xsl:for-each>
```

the context item is the integer value so you simply need to access `.` or `current()`.